# Delete table row php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

What is the problem with my code?

My PHP is working, but delete button doesn't work!

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                $ID = $_POST['value'];
                $delete = "DELETE FROM tbl_document WHERE ID = $ID";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$delete);
            }
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_document LIMIT $start, $end";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            echo "<table border='1' width='300' height='160' align = center id='result'>";
            echo '<tr>
                     <th width="80">ID</th>
                     <th width="200">Title</th>
                     <th width="260">Presented To</th>
                     <th width="260">Presented By</th>
                     <th width="160">Date Submitted</th>
                     <th>Location</th>
                     <th width="17%">Option</th>
                </tr>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr align = center >";
                <td width='20' height='60'>" .$row['ID']. "</td>";
                <td width='120' height='60'>" .$row['Title']. "</td>";
                <td>" .$row['Presented_To']. "</td>";
                <td>" .$row['Presented_By']. "</td>";
                <td>" .$row['Date_Submitted']. "</td>";
                <td>" .$row['Location']. "</td>";
"<td width='17%'>";
                ?>
                <?php if($_SESSION['user'] == "1")
                ?>
<button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-border-large w3-circle" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" name="delete" style="width:40%"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";
```

Comment: One big problem - It appears to be 100% missing!  Pesky code just can't keep still...

Comment: Please post your code, I think you forgot it.

Comment: Code please!!!!

Comment: post your CODE. as TEXT. not as screenshot. just use copy and paste.

Comment: where can i post the code?

Comment: edit your original post.

Comment: lol, he/she is new, @Leira use the edit link under you question to edit your question, and paste the code there, put 4 ` ` spaces before each line to take a `code` effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `button` is not enough to send data, you need to contain it within a `form`.

Here is how it should look like:

```
<form method="post">
  <button name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="w3-btn w3-red w3-border-large w3-circle" style="width:40%"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it works but the $ID = $_POST['value']; is undefined

Comment: That should be: `$ID = $_POST['delete'];`